# c# combobox automaticaly populated by inputed mysql data

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, combobox

I have two user controls. One is to input data and another one has a combobox that displays data from my MySQL table.

The use types in data in the first user control and presses a button.  This adds the data to a MySQL table.  I want to add the data immediately / automatically into the combobox (the other user control).

I would prefer not doing it using an event.  If it is not possible and I have to use an event, what event should I use?  Can it be an event not associated to the button?

Here is the method that reads data from MySQL and adds it to the combobox :

```
private void LoadFromDatabase()
{
    string query = "select name from country";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
    MySqlDataReader Read;
    conn.Open();
    Read = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(Read.Read())
    {
        metroComboBox1.Items.Add(Read.GetString("name"));
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

The current result is that I must reload the windows form to load the new data into thecombobox.  Without the reload, the combobox only displays the old data.  I have put that method under `InitializeComponent();` of the combobox user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event click on the comboBox itself, so whenever you click it to open the dropdown it will update the combobox. Make sure to clear the items at the top of the click event to prevent duplicates.

If you truly insist on having no events, you can use a background worker, however for what you're doing it seems like overkill to spawn a thread just for that.

This is an idea of what the final result should look like.

```
private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    LoadFromDatabase();

    comboBox1.SelectedItem = 0;
    comboBox1.Text = "Select Item";
}
```

Comment: did you mean set index to 0 or clear added item when not clicked?

Comment: You want to clear everything, and set the index to 0. (Check the updated solution for an idea of what the end result would be)